# Closure on CPU bottleneck, "opinion-based"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1758289/1010638) closed as opinion-based, but not [this](https://superuser.com/q/1031503/1010638)? Latter is less focused and more open to speculation, like many other `performance`-tagged questions I've seen. Former should be answerable objectively and with generality.

Would it still be closed if I didn't mention SSD and RAM? If yes, then that's closure despite an  objective answer? If no, then how does partially answering own question invalidate the question?

Comment: “Would it still be closed if I didn't mention SSD and RAM?” - Yes; You are still asking for a list of operations within a Python script that could be a bottleneck single threaded CPU I/O. Your question is extremely broad, that list, wouldn’t easily be produced without understanding what operations your script does, even then, you could easily benchmark your own script. **The other question should have been closed 7 years ago.**

Comment: @Ramhound Python is one part of my question. I won't go case-by-case but this network certainly doesn't strike me as demanding a math-level specificity in answerability, I don't see how a general-purpose answer that's right most of the time constitutes a bad question here. If I were a newbie, "RAM and SSD" would be immensely helpful - I just wish to know if I'm missing some other basic thing.

Comment: Re: other question - yet it's clearly well-received and likely helped many. I don't see harm from an unanswered question that goes stale, yet value _is_ lost from excessive closure.

Comment: Multiple users within the community have reviewed your question as it is, and voted to keep your question closed, so perhaps you should continue to edit your question and refine it? The other question received a single upvote in 7 years, that’s hardly well received, that’s overlooked

Comment: I recalled wrong on the other question, my mistake, but there's examples all over SE that qualify.

Comment: This community can’t do anything about contributions in other communities. Have you edited your question so it can be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

Super User is not well-suited for open-ended questions. It is for solving actual problems you have. From [the help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

That’s not the main problem I see however. Because of how “loose” your question is, you could write an entire computer science article in answer. The help center says this:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

I do not agree that your question is opinion-based. However, it should probably have been closed anyway. It smells research-y and is also more about computer theory.